# UPnP-Server behind Firewall won't show up in iOS-Apps

Tags: networking, vlc-media-player, ios, ipad, upnp

I'm in the middle of setting up a server net at home. The firewall between user and server net does UPnP-Routing via smcroute (and firewalling with iptables plus ipset). All in all it works perfectly. On my PCs and on my Android phone the media server (minidlna) gets found an serves the media files without question. 
Only the iOS devices (iPad and iPhone) make trouble. VLC recognizes the server here too, but the iOS version doesn't support resuming to an earlier timestamp after stopping the video. And two other apps don't find the server (in particular XtremePlayer which would be the first choice).

Does anyone have a clue what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance and some more happy holiday hours.

The Becheesus

Comment: In addition: BubbleUPnP on Android finds the server, too. It seems to be an iOS issue (but, of course, that would contradict the fact that VLC is able to recognize the minidlna also on iOS). I really don't have any clue...

Comment: Another addition: tcpdump on the firewall shows traffic on udp port 1900 (UPnP) coming from the address of the iPad (to 239.255.255.250) when i open the XtremePlayer - but it doesn't get to the server (also tested with tcpdump). When I use VLC, it gets though to the server in the other subnet.

Comment: In the meantime I've made another observation: my Samsung smart TV also doesn't find the media server on the other subnet but the traffic as captured with tcpdump looks a bit different. On the fw it shows packets from the wlan router/internet gateway (Fritzbox 7490) and on the server there are also packets from the Fritzbox being captured. Normally you can see the actual ip addresses of the upnp clients and the server on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with help from another forum I was able to identify the cause of this malfunction. The players that won't find the server send request packets with a TTL of 1 on the IP layer. Hence they aren't routable at all... The functioning ones (e.g. VLC) use higher values for TTL (in the case of VLC: 4).
So, albeit I'm not able to fix this for good now I'm glad to know what's going on.